# using max and count using sql

Tags: mysql, sql, count

Find the region having maximum customers (display the region name and
max(no_of_customers)

```
select c.Region,max(total) 
from (select c.Region,count(c.Cust_id) as total
    from cust_dimen c
    group by Region) as total;
```

but it shows wrong

```
SELECT region
FROM cust_dimen
GROUP BY region
HAVING COUNT(cust_id)=
    (SELECT MAX(t) FROM
        (SELECT region,COUNT(cust_id) AS t,count(Cust_id) as total
         FROM cust_dimen
         GROUP BY region) t1);
```

it shows region but i need even the count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT region, COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id) AS cnt
FROM cust_dimen
GROUP BY region
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id) =
(SELECT MAX(cnt)
 FROM
 (SELECT region, COUNT(DISTINCT cust_id) AS cnt
  FROM cust_dimen
  GROUP BY region) sub)
```

You are close - just add the count in your select statement.

Comment: ya i was waiting for this one bro , i did to know what is my mistake thanks a lot bro

Answer (score 1):

Just use `order by` and `limit`:

```
select c.Region, count(*) as total
from cust_dimen c
group by Region
order by total desc
limit 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Intentalo asi:
SELECT region,COUNT(cust_id)number FROM cust_dimenGROUP BY region ORDER BY number DESC LIMIT 1